# Best way to plot top n elements by month?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've this df, with the top 3 cap (episodes of tv series) for each month of 2019.

**What is the best way to plot them to show the top 3 caps for each month?**

I'm trying to plot these episodes by month using `geom_bar()` but it plot all caps for each month (showing only data that correspond to the current month).

I'd like to show only the caps of that month on the y axi, not all the episodes.

**Plot:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKRNi.png)

**df:**

```
structure(list(mes = c("Abril", "Abril", "Abril", "Agosto", "Agosto", 
"Agosto", "Diciembre", "Diciembre", "Diciembre", "Enero", "Enero", 
"Enero", "Enero", "Enero", "Enero", "Enero", "Febrero", "Febrero", 
"Febrero", "Julio", "Julio", "Julio", "Junio", "Junio", "Junio", 
"Junio", "Marzo", "Marzo", "Marzo", "Mayo", "Mayo", "Mayo", "Mayo", 
"Noviembre", "Noviembre", "Noviembre", "Octubre", "Octubre", 
"Octubre", "Setiembre", "Setiembre", "Setiembre", "Setiembre"
), temporada_final = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cap = c("  1", "  10", "  11", "  18", 
"  19", "  32", "  1", "  32", "  33", "  151", "  156", "  166", 
"  168", "  176", "  177", "  193", "  104", "  105", "  194", 
"  1", "  122", "  2", "  1", "  130", "  179", "  194", "  104", 
"  105", "  194", "  1", "  156", "  194", "  27", "  1", "  3", 
"  4", "  1", "  178", "  2", "  1", "  3", "  5", "  54"), totalEvents = c(6L, 
6L, 13L, 19L, 14L, 34L, 27L, 29L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 29L, 10L, 11L, 27L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 23L, 14L, 8L, 
19L, 14L, 14L, 22L, 37L, 26L, 19L, 33L, 17L, 19L, 48L, 25L, 25L, 
30L)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(mes = c("Abril", 
"Agosto", "Diciembre", "Enero", "Febrero", "Julio", "Junio", 
"Marzo", "Mayo", "Noviembre", "Octubre", "Setiembre"), temporada_final = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 
    10:16, 17:19, 20:22, 23:26, 27:29, 30:33, 34:36, 37:39, 40:43)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

**current ggplot code:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cap, y = totalEvents, label = comma(totalEvents))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="#b661f2") +
  facet_wrap(~ mes) +
  labs(title = title, subtitle=subtitle,
       x = x_title, y = y_title) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=18,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", vjust=2, size = 22),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="grey40", size=8, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="grey10", size=12, face="bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 22,
                                    hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(hjust = -0.4, size = 6)
```

Comment: it looks like there is a lot of information here that is not entirely relevant to the problem you're having. please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Thanks Dave, but I've shown the plot that I've, the data to be used and the problem, to know if there is a better way to show this: caps with more events by month. Don't understand why you point me to how to ask a question. All relevant data is in here.

Comment: sure, but this is not a *minimal* example. you are asking SO contributors to sort through irrelevant information, so you're less likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if it is what you are looking for, but try:

```
facet_wrap(~ mes, scales = "free_y")
```

This will give you only the caps of each month on the y-axes of the individual facets.